# Machine Learning predictions using dates

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, regression

So I created a machine learning model to make predictions on future output at work. So far its 97% accurate.

I wanted to predict the output using the date along with 2 other inputs and since you can't use datetime directly in regression models.

I converted the date column using ordinal encoding, will I then be able to use the date as an input then?

Or is there a better method?

Comment: Hi Nyiko  This question is pretty open-ended at the moment. You might get better answers if you (1) show some code, and (2) focus on a specific problem rather than "is there a better method." `scikit-learn` has an extended guide on time-series feature engineering and different approaches for date encoding that may be helpful: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_cyclical_feature_engineering.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinal encoding is't the best approach for handling date/time data, especially if in your data occurs seasonality or trends. Depending on your problem, you could extract a lot of different features from dates, e.q:

- year, month, day ....
- hour, minute, second ....
- day of week
- season
- holiday
- etc ...

What should you use exactly highly depends on your problem, you should first investigate your data, maybe plot your predicted variable against dates and search for patterns which can help you then achieve best prediction results.